# Using Active Directory authentication on a internal website

Tags: asp.net, authentication, active-directory

My situation is I've created a small website that does a few simple sql queries and updating. One or two of the commands should only be accessed by certain people. The website is on one of our servers so anyone who accesses will already be logged in to AD.

I’ve only done web design when needed and isn’t part of my normal duties and only used it when needed so I’m in need of some guidance.

I know I could create a whole logging in and cookies system or something but it sounds like as only people who are already logged in wouldn’t need that and I would be making the task overly complicated.

Essentially I need the easiest way to allow a situation where only certain AD users can click on a button, is the only way possible making a log in page? 
I would really appreciate some pointers in the right direction it doesn’t have to be copy and paste code answers.

Comment: Your page can automatically authenticate people against AD so you know who is viewing. You'd then keep your own permissions database somewhere and tie the two together to decide if they have access. There are lots of samples for ASP .NET already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all your users are already authenticated against AD then it would probably be simpler to get their credentials and check their user ID against a lookup list of allowed users which you could hold in a database table.

You could then show or hide, or disable and enable, the relevant controls depending on whether they were found in the lookup.

It would make a pretty seamless experience for the user at the expense of having to maintain the lookup.

Alternatively, you could restrict access based on checking if the user was a member of a particular AD group, which eliminates the lookup table but then requires suitable domain administrator privileges in order to add and remove people from the group.

Comment: Thanks for the help, managed to figure it out from your answer as it helped me find the correct key words to use.

Comment: No problem. I would have had take some time to refresh my memory of the exact classes to use, but you did say pointers would be fine rather than an full walk-through. :)